# targeting jth-kth element in a matirx using python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

[image]

I would like to implement a matrix that satisfies the conditions shown in the image:

1. The matrix is an `m * n` matrix
2. The `j, k`th element will be 1 if either the `k`th index is `j + 1` or `k`th index is 2 or the `j`th index is 2

Here is my latest code:

```
self.ylmaxvect = [1, 2, 3, 4]
self.ylmax = int(input('inputylmax'))
self.An = sum(self.ylmaxvect)
self.Am = sum(self.ylmaxvect)

# -------------declare a zero matrix first------------------------ #
self.matAL = np.zeros((self.An, self.Am))
for i in range(self.An - 1):
    if self.matAL[i][i + 1] == 0:
        if i  == self.ylmax:
            self.matAL[i][i + 1] = 1
        else:
   self.matAL[i][i + 1] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking this. Start with

```
A = np.zeros((m, n))
```

The condition `k = j + 1` is just the first diagonal above the main one. You can use [`np.fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) for that:

```
np.fill_diagonal(A[:, 1:], 1)
```

This works because the slice `A[:, 1:]` is a view into the original matrix, and therefore any modifications to it are visible in the underlying matrix.

The conditions `k = 2` and `j = 2` are just slices across the appropriate dimension:

```
A[:, 1] = 1
A[1, :] = 1
```

I'm assuming that your matrix notation is one-based, while numpy is zero based. If not, change the ones in the index to two.

You can visualize what `fill_diag` is doing by generating the `j` and `k` indices yourself. `k` goes `1, 2, 3, ...`. `j` goes `0, 1, 2, ...`. How far do they go? Well, the lesser of `m - 1` and `n`, since it depends on the shape:

```
j = np.arange(min(m - 1, n))
k = j + 1
A[j, k] = 1
```

If you want to use loops, you can do this in `O(m + n)` rather than `O(m * n)` time. The key is that you know where the ones go: you don't need to check each element:

```
for j in range(m):
    A[j, 2] = A[j, j + 1] = 1
for k in range(n):
    A[2, k] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly less numpy-specific method:

```
import numpy as np

m = int(input("m: "))
n = int(input("n: "))
mat = np.zeros((m,n))
for j in range(0, m):
    for k in range(0, n):
        if (k == j + 1) or k == 2 or j == 2:
            mat[j, k] = 1
print(mat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also flatten the array and explicitly update the values:

```
import numpy as np
m,n     = 14,9
D       = np.arange(n,min(n**2+n,n*m),n+1)
X       = np.zeros(m*n,'int')
X[D]    = 1
X.shape = (m,n)
X[:,2]  = 1
X[2,:]  = 1
print(X)
```

Comment: It's more standard to call `reshape` than to assign `shape` directly, but this is neat.

Comment: I don't know why that would be considered more standard. Isn't reshape just the function that updates the .shape? If reshape is doing something more it would be interesting to know what.

Answer (score 0):

creating a zeros array

```
>>> m, n = 5, 4
>>> 
>>> 
>>> arr = np.zeros(shape= [m, n])
>>> arr
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

assigning `1` to second row and column, and to the main diagonal offset by 1

```
>>> arr[2, :] = 1
>>> arr[:, 2] = 1
>>> arr.ravel()[1::n+1] = 1
>>> 
>>> arr
array([[0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 1., 0.]])
```